# Ubuntu budgie 18.04 to ubuntu 18.04, can it be done in terminal?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a community based flavor of ubuntu 18.04 called budgie. Instead of writing a new ubuntu 18.04 to a flashdrive/disc and installing the system from scratch. 
Can you do the equivalent with only terminal commands? Or is it simply impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tasksel` command line tool to add and remove the different software collections and configurations that are bundled with each flavour of Ubuntu, effectively "reflavouring" your installation, along with other general system tasks (OpenSSH server, mail stack, etc.).

Install it with `sudo apt install tasksel`.

Make sure to read `man tasksel` and update your backups *before* you start the procedure.